# Problem: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message [10008]

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a purge command right now (following reconlx's Purge Command tutorial for DJS v13), and I keep receiving a `DiscordAPI` Error.

The command only works once, however, it doesn't reply with embeds like it's supposed to, then crashes along with every other command there is. It does become functional again after a certain period of time then the cycle repeats over and over again.

I have made sure that I had the right intents (which I do) and such, but nothing seems to work... I have no idea what in the world is causing the error. Anyone who would be willing to help is doing me a favour.

Oh, and here's the code for purge.js and the error in question down below.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports = {
    name: "purge",
    description: "Purges messages",
    userPermissions: ["MANAGE_MESSAGES"],
    options: [
        {
            name: "amount",
            description: "Amount of messages to purge",
            type: "INTEGER",
            required: true,
        },
    ],

    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        const amount = interaction.options.getInteger("amount");

        const limitEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#2F3136")
            .setTitle("You may only purge 100 messages at a time!")
            .setFooter({ text: "Error: Limit Reached" })

        if (amount > 100) 
            return interaction.followUp({ 
                embeds: 
                    [limitEmbed], 
            });

        const messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch({ 
            limit: amount + 1,
        });

        const filtered = messages.filter(
            (msg) => Date.now() - msg.createdTimestamp < ms("14 days")
        );

        await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(filtered)

        const successEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#2F3136")
            .setTitle(`Successfully purged ${filtered.size - 1} messages!`)
            .setFooter({ text: "Action Successfully Performed" })

        interaction.followUp({ 
            embeds: 
                [successEmbed],
        });
    },
};
```

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Tonkotsu\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Tonkotsu\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async InteractionWebhook.send (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Tonkotsu\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:196:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/webhooks/950050048618688572/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTk5MjYyNTIyMTc3NzQ5MDAzOmhGaUJVQkF6YjduVUlZNTJsT1MwV254T2FYdEJiaUNMWDdwUWloYzhyNnJudERLMHhxak96RTlkTmpDQW5sdEhONnhKSGkyZkdlQndmWGJQSFM0dk52bGduZ3hBTlE3S3g4R2JBRWFRdDNEbmtrb3Z6a0hpVk8yU2hIYllyemhm?wait=true',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: 'Successfully purged 3 messages!',
          type: 'rich',
          description: null,
          url: null,
          timestamp: 0,
          color: 3092790,
          fields: [],
          thumbnail: null,
          image: null,
          author: null,
          footer: {
            text: 'Action Successfully Performed',
            icon_url: undefined
          }
        }
      ],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `interaction.channel.send` instead of `interaction.followUp`?

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks! 

Although, I do wonder if there's an explanation behind this. If you could somehow explain (for future reference) then that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`interaction.reply(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) instead of [`interaction.followUp(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=followUp), `followUp` is used when you already replied to a message and want to continue replying to the interaction. So it will throw an error if you trying to use it on an interaction who hasn't been replied yet.